# error: invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

I was trying to compile the code from a third party and got the error:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression
>
> ('boost::archive::binary_oarchive' and 'Tree *') oa << this;

I believe it is illegal to pass `this` to `oa` using `<<`. But can anyone tell me how to start fixing it?

This is the source code:

```
void save(std::string path) {
    try {
        std::ofstream ofs(path.c_str());
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << this;
        ofs.flush();
        ofs.close();
        std::cout << "saved " << path << std::endl;
    } catch (boost::archive::archive_exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Archive Exception during serializing:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "it was tree: " << path << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that?

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix it without knowing what `Tree` is. Perhaps you meant `oa << *this` but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit: Actually, what @LightnessRacesinOrbit says makes more sense: you probably just need to dereference the `this` pointer]

It seems like `operator <<` isn't defined for class `Tree`. It would need to conform to whatever format `boost::archive::binary_oarchive` is expecting.

A definition of `operator <<` for `Tree` would be:

```
boost::archive::binary_oarchive& operator<<(boost::archive::binary_oarchive& os, const Tree& dt)
{
    // TODO: serialise 'tree' into 'os' 

    return os;
}
```

If you need to use private fields of the `Tree` class, make it a [friend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) function by putting the following inside `Tree`'s declaration:

```
boost::archive::binary_oarchive& operator<<(boost::archive::binary_oarchive& os, const Tree& dt)
```